# How can I position a div relative to a list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an unordered list of pictures, and when I hover over one I want the two pictures to the left to fade out, and a div to appear in their place with text. I've gotten this working, except for positioning the div - I've tried this:

```
div.position({my: 'left top', at: 'left top', of: other_list_item});
```

but that just returns an Object ( the new location ) of {left: 0, top: 0}.

I've also tried putting the div in another li element, but it's still a no-go. Here's the div HTML:

```
<div style="width: 255px; height: 110px; position: absolute;" id="name_popup"><p>Jon Jensen</p><p>Chief Technical Officer</p><p>London, England</p></div>
```

***EDIT*** I'm working on a JSFiddle example, but there's kind of a lot to put in, so idk when it'll be ready. Anyways, I forgot to mention this bit of fun:

when I call .position() by itself on the element that I'm trying to anchor to, it returns the correct offsets, but when I try to use position() on the other element to match their positions, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'll try to get a simple fake working - however, the pictures are private, and I've been doing most of my work in Chrome's Developer Tools until I get it working

Comment: So use fake pictures that are the same size

Comment: Is the first example a CSS rule you've used? Write a proper CSS, and add `position: relative;` to the hosting `li` element. Absolutely positioned elements are positioned related to nearest positioned parent element, if none found, `body` is used.

Comment: @Cornholio Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CFGW/). If you'll remove the rule for `li`, you can see what I meant in a comment above.

Comment: @Teemu - that looks great, except that I need to position it relative to other list elements than the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand the question, but from my reasoning I get that you are trying to position new divs in place of the faded out images, so here is some code that could fit your situation

```
$('div').click(function(){
    //get the positions of the divs to be faded out
    var prev_position = $(this).prev('div').position();
    var next_position = $(this).next('div').position();
    //create and position new divs
    $(this).insertBefore('<div style="position:absolute;top:' +prev_position.top+ 'px;left:' +prev_position.left+ 'px;">Replacing DIV</div>');
    $(this).insertAfter('<div style="position:absolute;top:' +next_position.top+ 'px;left:' +next_position.left+ 'px;">Replacing DIV</div>');
    //hide the divs
    $(this).prev('div').fadeOut();
    $(this).next('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Sometimes, if your parent element has a position set, then the .position() will get the position relative to the parent element, and depending in your needs this might throw off your design. So instead you could get the coordinates of the previous and next divs relative to the WINDOW and you could get those like these:

```
    function getPosition($el){
        //get the offset coordinates of the recently clicked link
        var offset = $el.offset();
        var top = offset.top;
        var left = offset.left;
        //get position of this link relative to the window
        var rel_top = top - $(window).scrollTop();
        var rel_left = left - $(window).scrollLeft();
    }
```